# Animate maskedCorners in Swift when some corners are always rounded?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, rounded-corners, cornerradius

I have a rect. Top corners are always rounded. Bottom corners have animation - rounded or not.

Previous my solution was to split this rect into top and bottom rects (top one is constant, bottom one is animated). The reason is `maskedCorners` is not animated - you can animate `cornerRadius` only.

But now I need to add a colored border around the rect which should be animated too. So my solution is not suitable anymore. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by animating a `CGPath` for the view's layer, and constructing the path by adding arcs at the corners for individual radii.

Here's an example class:

```
class AnimCornerView: UIView  {
    
    public var fillColor: UIColor = .white
    public var borderColor: UIColor = .clear
    public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

    private var _tl: CGFloat = 0
    private var _tr: CGFloat = 0
    private var _bl: CGFloat = 0
    private var _br: CGFloat = 0

    private var theShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        theShapeLayer = self.layer as? CAShapeLayer
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setCorners(topLeft: _tl, topRight: _tr, botLeft: _bl, botRight: _br, animated: false)
    }

    public func setCorners(topLeft tl: CGFloat, topRight tr: CGFloat, botLeft bl: CGFloat, botRight br: CGFloat, animated: Bool, duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.3) -> Void {
        
        _tl = tl
        _tr = tr
        _bl = bl
        _br = br
        
        theShapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        theShapeLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        theShapeLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        
        let newPath: CGPath = getPath(topLeft: tl, topRight: tr, botLeft: bl, botRight: br)
        
        if animated {
            
            CATransaction.begin()
            
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
            animation.duration = duration
            animation.toValue = newPath
            animation.fillMode = .forwards
            animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
                self.theShapeLayer.path = newPath
                self.theShapeLayer.removeAllAnimations()
            })
            
            self.theShapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "path")
            
            CATransaction.commit()
            
        } else {
            
            theShapeLayer.path = newPath
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private func getPath(topLeft tl: CGFloat, topRight tr: CGFloat, botLeft bl: CGFloat, botRight br: CGFloat) -> CGPath {
        
        var pt = CGPoint.zero
        
        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()
        
        // top-left corner plus top-left radius
        pt.x = tl
        pt.y = 0
        
        myBezier.move(to: pt)
        
        pt.x = bounds.maxX - tr
        pt.y = 0
        
        // add "top line"
        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)
        
        pt.x = bounds.maxX - tr
        pt.y = tr

        // add "top-right corner"
        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: tr, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
        
        pt.x = bounds.maxX
        pt.y = bounds.maxY - br
        
        // add "right-side line"
        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)
        
        pt.x = bounds.maxX - br
        pt.y = bounds.maxY - br
        
        // add "bottom-right corner"
        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: br, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)
        
        pt.x = bl
        pt.y = bounds.maxY
        
        // add "bottom line"
        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)
        
        pt.x = bl
        pt.y = bounds.maxY - bl
        
        // add "bottom-left corner"
        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: bl, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
        
        pt.x = 0
        pt.y = tl
        
        // add "left-side line"
        myBezier.addLine(to: pt)
        
        pt.x = tl
        pt.y = tl
        
        // add "top-left corner"
        myBezier.addArc(withCenter: pt, radius: tl, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)
        
        myBezier.close()
        
        return myBezier.cgPath
        
    }
    
}
```

You can specify different radii for each corner, and tell it to animate to the new settings (or not).

For example, you could start with:

```
testView.setCorners(topLeft: 40, topRight: 40, botLeft: 0, botRight: 0, animated: false)
```

to round the top-left and top-right corners, then later call:

```
testView.setCorners(topLeft: 40, topRight: 40, botLeft: 40, botRight: 40, animated: true)
```

to animate the bottom corners.

Here's a sample controller class to demonstrate. Each time you tap, the bottom corners will animate between rounded and non-rounded:

```
class AnimCornersViewController : UIViewController {

    let testView: AnimCornerView = {
        let v = AnimCornerView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.fillColor = .green
        v.borderColor = .blue
        v.borderWidth = 2
        v.setCorners(topLeft: 40, topRight: 40, botLeft: 0, botRight: 0, animated: false)
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
        
    }

    var shouldRoundBottom: Bool = false
    
    @objc func gotTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
        
        shouldRoundBottom.toggle()
        
        if shouldRoundBottom {
            testView.setCorners(topLeft: 40, topRight: 40, botLeft: 40, botRight: 40, animated: true)
        } else {
            testView.setCorners(topLeft: 40, topRight: 40, botLeft: 0, botRight: 0, animated: true)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**Note:** this is ***example code only!!!***